# PIG: Cannot turn (key, (tuple_of_3_things)) into (key, tupelement1, tupelement2, tupelement3)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a relation, reflat1. Below are the output of DESCRIBE and DUMP.

```
reflat1: {cookie: chararray,tupofstuff: (category: chararray,weight: double,lasttime: long)}
(key1,(613,1.0,1410155702)   
(key2,(iOS,1.0,1410155702)
(key3,(G.M.,1.0,1410155702)
```

Yes, I notice that the parentheses do not get closed. I have no clue why. Perhaps the reason there are no parentheses is the source of all of my problems.

I want to transform it to a relation (let's call it reflat2) with 4 fields, which would *ideally* look like:

```
(key1, 613, 1.0,1410155702)   
(key2, iOS, 1.0,1410155702)
(key3, G.M., 1.0,1410155702)
```

But my code is NOT working. Below is the relevant bit.

```
reflat2 = foreach reflat1 {
  GENERATE 
  cookie                  as cookie,
  tupofstuff.(category)   as category,
  tupofstuff.(weight)     as weight,
  tupofstuff.(lasttime)   as lasttime;
};
r1 = LIMIT reflat2 100;
dump r1;
```

Which leads to the schema I'd expect:

```
DESCRIBE reflat2
reflat2: {cookie: chararray,category: chararray,weight: double,lasttime: long}
```

But gives an error on the dump:

```
Unable to open iterator for alias r1
```

When I look at the errors on the failed MapReduce jobs, I see:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.pig.data.Tuple
```

Which is weird, because if anything I'm casting a tuple to a string (and a double and a long), not vice versa.

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 0):

Using FLATTEN on TUPLE brings the elements of tuples outside. You should use flatten as below:

```
reflat2 = foreach reflat1 GENERATE cookie, FLATTEN(tupofstuff);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried that as well and it gives me the exact same error.

Comment: @jarfa Could you update the question to include what you tried, and directly make sure that you show a reproducible example with proper inputs? (The inputs you give seem a bit dodgy, so just start with something that has to be correct beyond doubt)